# XBuild reporting too many project files but works with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, xbuild

I'm running the following msbuild command

> msbuild /verbosity:normal /property:configuration="Release"
>   /property:VisualStudioVersion="12.0" /m /property:RunOctoPack="true"
>   /property:OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles="true" /target:"Clean" ../MYSLN.sln

which builds successfully.

I just tried running the same command using xbuild on OSX so:

> xbuild /verbosity:normal /property:configuration="Release"
>   /property:VisualStudioVersion="12.0" /m /property:RunOctoPack="true"
>   /property:OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles="true" /target:"Clean" ../MYSLN.sln

which reports

> MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified

I have XBuild Engine Version 12.0 and Mono, Version 4.0.2.0

Is there some subtle mistake in how I'm listing the parameters

----EDIT----

That's being thrown here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/xbuild/Parameters.cs#L140 which suggests that xbuild isn't picking up the solution file (I think)

NB, I've tried with the solution file as the first and last parameter to no avail

----EDIT----

I've added that the solution file has an uppercase name in case that is important.

----EDIT----

Ah, I've been writing a test around their parameter parsing code and it isn't recognising /m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I grabbed their source and wrote a test to see what was happening. And xamarin doesn't recognise the /m parameter. That's a real parameter for xbuild so I've logged https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33388 to see if they purposefully don't support it

TLDR; currently xbuild doesn't support /m as a parameter